# Angular js : hide html and show loader until all html are read for display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making an application in angular-js (with required js).I want to show a splash loader until all the html on the page gets ready for the display to user.

Boos trapping  the app via required as

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);
    app.init = function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    }
```

My nglCloak directive look like this

```
DirectivesModule.directive('ngCloak', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', '$timeout', 'header',
        function($http, $rootScope, $timeout, $q, $timeout, header) {
            return {
                priority: 0,
                compile: function(element, attr) {
                    document.getElementById("loading_screen_logo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("loading_screen_background").style.backgroundImage = "none";
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

My html

```
    <body class="page-body" ng-controller="cusAppController">
  <div class="ocntainer" id="loading_screen_background" >
    <div id="loading_screen_logo" style="display:block" ></div>
    <span ng-cloak >

    /*all html content goes here*/

    </span>
 </div>
 <script data-main="../../themes/myTheme/js/main" src="../../themes/myTheme/source/js/require.js"></script>
</body>
```

My Css

```
 [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
     display: none !important;
    }

   #loading_screen_background {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
        z-index: 0;
        /*-webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(black));*/
    }

    #loading_screen_logo{
        text-align: center;
        background-image: url('../../themes/ngCus/images/app_loader_80_80.gif');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100000;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

After few work i found ng-cloak directive which executes after all the directive gets compiled as mentioned in angular docs.For the data i have put my api calls in resolve so the data is present before the route change.

The above approach works for few api call and few html componenton the page. but when my html component gets more my page get displayed with blank, loading component one by one as the html gets ready by directive or template.

Any one has idea how can i handle this ? The intended effect is as gmail does when we log in.

Comment: It sounds as if you're taking the right approach. Can you post some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: @MarcKline : can you please look into it , i have added the code.

Comment: Can you post the problem in a JS Fiddle?  So basically you want to show "loading..." like Gmail does until absolutely everything is done loading?